# getView() calls position 0 instead of the last

Tags: android, android-view, listadapter

Here is my `getView()`:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        //MessageModel mm = messageModels.get(position);
        if(!messageModels.get(position).isIncoming()){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_messages_outgoing, null);
        }else {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_messages_incoming, null);
        }

        //only for debugging purpose
        Log.i(tag, position+", id: "+messageModels.get(position).getId()+", isIncoming: "+
                messageModels.get(position).isIncoming()+", msg: "+messageModels.get(position).getMessage());

        holder                      = new Holder();
        holder.tvMessage            = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        holder.tvTime               = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvMessage.setText(messageModels.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.tvTime.setText(messageModels.get(position).getTime());

    return convertView;
}
```

From the log I find the following:

```
0, id: 11, isIncoming: true, msg: hi
1, id: 14, isIncoming: false, msg: hmmm
0, id: 11, isIncoming: true, msg: hi
```

That is the first index is being repeated for the last. I tried for larger item numbers it always calls position like this: `0, 1, 2, 3, ... n-2, 0` so I miss the `n-1`th (last) position. Where should I change?

Comment: If you have `n` items in your list, the last one will have index `n-1`. Additionally, there is no guarantee how many times or in which order the `getView()` method may be called, so that's why you're seeing `0`th position getting called more than once.

Comment: My mistake. Just edited and thanks :)
How can I make sure that I can add `n-1`th data get added to the list?

Comment: Well, `getView()` is generally only going to be called for the visible items (kinda), so if `n-1` is off-screen, you won't see that in the log until you scroll to it. If you're just not seeing that item at all, then the problem is most likely elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Override the function getCount() in your adapter class. And return
>   messageModels.size() from there, looks like you may be returning 
>   (messageModels.size() - 1) from there.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messageModels.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this line `android:stackFromBottom="true"` in my layout was causing this. I removed it and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this return position 0 in last item:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.foo_row, null);
        fooModel = this.getItem(position);
        //proceed with fooModel
    }

    return view;
}
```

Change it to below solved the problem:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.foo_row, parent, false);
    }
    fooModel = this.getItem(position);
    //proceed with fooModel

    return convertView;
}
```

Also don't forget to reset view properties in if-else condition checking, e.g.:

```
if (fooModel.name != null) { yourView.setText(fooModel.name);  }
else { yourView.setText(''); }
```